# Flipping screens

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

I am using a MacBook Pro (Catalina, version 10.15.5). When I click on the adobe icon at the bottom of my screen, the screen switches to another screen. Likewise, when I click on the microsoft teams icon at the bottom of my screen, it switches to another screen.

I only want one screen, however. How can avoid this problem, ensuring that when I click on the microsoft teams/adobe/etcetera it opens in the same screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using apps in fullscreen.
All fullscreen apps get their own Space. There is no way around this.

The only 'fix' is to not use fullscreen.

Comment: Maybe I am not clear in what the problem is. Usually, when I open a pdf file, it opens in the same screen. But now it is flipping to another screen. The same with Microsoft Teams: usually I click on the Microsoft Teams icon, and it opens in the same screen.

Comment: Look at Mission Control (default key command is Ctrl/up arrow or F3) Do you see several tabs at the top called 'Desktop 1' Desktop 2' etc, or do you see application names? If you see Desktops you have multiple Spaces enabled (which must have been done manually). If you see application names you are running those apps in fullscreen. Cmd/ctrl/F will toggle fullscreen.

Comment: Yes, I have "Desktop 1" and "Desktop 2". How can I unify them?

Comment: Hold your cursor over each one you don't want & click the X

Comment: Is there no way to 'transfer across' material from Desktop 2 to Desktop 1? Also, why did this happen in the first place? Did I press some button to make it happen?

Comment: If you remove Spaces, apps will fold back to the remaining Space. Yes, you had to have added those manually at some point by clicking the + button to the right.

Comment: How do I remove Spaces?

Comment: Ah, you can drag things from one to the other. :)